# Use role_arn defined in aws config file in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, config

I have a Java code which creates a s3Client object to perform bucket operations. I have a **`credentials`** file with the following data under `/root/.aws/` folder,

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <the key>
aws_secret_access_key = <the key>
```

Most recently, the bucket policies got updated and the following details were added in a **`config`** file under the same directory,

```
[default]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<id>:role/<role_name>
source_profile = default
output = text
region = region-name
```

My application is not able to consume the `role_arn` from the config file, and can not do any bucket operations.

Does AWS provides any classes to read the config file directly, I do not want to hardcode the `role_arn` and `region` values in the code.

I see **`ProfilesConfigFile`** for reading what is there in the credentials file, but nothing for the contents of the **`config`** file.

Comment: Can you paste how you are initializing s3Client  in your application? If you pass  `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` instance to s3Client constructor, It uses IAM role to access s3 buckets, provided role has required permissions on s3

Comment: I tried using `s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();` but it is only reading the credentials file and not the config file, and unable to pick the `role_arn` from the config file.

Answer (score 2):

AWS CLI uses config file (~/.aws/config) for delegating profiles using role_arn/region. So your cli operations with `--profile default` would work fine.As per this [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/803) role assumption as specified in config file is incompatible with AWS SDK.

When you initialize s3Client as below it uses `S3CredentialProviderChain` which simply extends [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) for retrieving credentials from ~/.aws/credentials.

Workaround to make your application is to load the config(~/.aws/config) file in application and make an assume request with the specified role_arn. [example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/delegating-api-access-to-aws-services-using-iam-roles/)